# How to get data from neo4j database and bind it into a grid view using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, database, neo4j, neo4jclient

I wrote this cypher query in C#:

```
var myClint = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"), "neo4j", "1412");
 myClint.Connect();

 var getName= myClint.Cypher.Match("(n:Person)
                      .Return(n => n.As<Person>())
                      .Results;
```

I have setters and getters in Person class to get the name, ssn, and age for everyone in the Person node. I want to display those information on a grid view. I did that with sql server but I do not know how to do it with neo4j.

Thanks in advance

https://stackoverflow.com/users/6771545/abd

Comment: What is your code for binding with SQL Server - are you trying to bind so you can edit / add etc using the DataGrid?

Comment: string abc = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString1"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(abc);
    
    con.Open();
    
     SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
       
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    
     cmd.CommandText = "select P.name, P.age from Person as P";
     
     SqlDataAdapter dAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    
    dAdapt.Fill(dt);
    
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    
    GridView1.DataBind();
    
   con.Close();

Comment: I have the same data on neo4j and SQL. I am learning the neo4j.

Answer (score 1):

In essence, you need to create your own `DataTable`, you can do it manually with code like this:

```
public static DataTable ConvertToTable(IEnumerable<Person> people)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt.Columns.Add("Age");

    foreach (var person in people)
    {
        var row = dt.NewRow();
        row[0] = person.Name;
        row[1] = person.Age;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

But that means you have to write one of those for each type, so you can do this instead:

```
public static DataTable ConvertToTableAutomatic<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (var property in properties)
        dt.Columns.Add(property.Name);

    foreach (var item in items)
        dt.Rows.Add(FillRow<T>(dt.NewRow(), item, properties));

    return dt;
}

private static DataRow FillRow<T>(DataRow row, T item, PropertyInfo[] properties)
{
    foreach (var property in properties)
        row[property.Name] = property.GetValue(item);

    return row;
}
```

But bear in mind - you won't be able to update the `Neo4j` DB with this, just **display** the information.